# Быстрое преобразование Фурье. Как выделить частоту ноты?

Tags: java, аудио, fft, музыка

Заинтересовался реализацией выделением нот и распознаванием сигналов исходя из нот.
Вот если взять фортепиано, записать звук пары клавиш, после чего применить БПФ, на выходе мы получим массив комплексных чисел, где амплитудой будет модуль комплексного числа, а аргумент его фазой. Вот немного не понятно как выделить частоту ноты?

Answer (score 3):

Преобразование фурье производится на комплексных числах.
На вход для преобразования следует подавать в реальную часть амплитуду(величину сигнала), а в мнимую часть нуль.

На выходе мы получим массив комплексных чисел, где амплитудой будет модуль комплексного числа, а аргумент его фазой. Каждый элемент массива представляет из себя одну гармонику, начиная с нулевой и завершая n-ой. Или это называется спектрами? В разных источниках на этот счёт разная информация.

Спектры/гармоники отделены друг от друга дискретным шагом равным частотам дискретизации/количество отсчётов. Количество отсчётов равно количеству чисел амплитуд на входе, длине массивов входящих комплексных чисел, количеству длины входного сэмпла. В общем, количеству комплексных чисел на входе.

Больше на входе отсчётов, больше разрешение по частоте на выходе.

То есть, на выходе получив 1024 значений комплексных получаем 1024 значений амплитуда-фаза. Из этих значений, располагая массив по порядку и амплитуде можно получить нечто вроде визуализации амплитуды звука по частоте.

Если дискретизация 44100Гц, а входной массив имеет длину 65536 то шаг между элементами массива на выходе получается 0.672912598 Гц.

В целях распознавания человеческой речи подобная точность бессмысленна и избыточна. Путём генетического алгоритма (естественного отбора человеческого вида в условиях среды планеты Земля) оптимальным максимальным будет шаг между частотами от 1 до 9 Гц, то есть на вход желательно подавать максимум 8192 значений амплитуды-времени для частоты дискретизации 44100.

Но прежде чем подавать эти данные на распознавание, с ними нужно ещё немного повозиться, но я не знаю как. Там что-то про окошки и что-то с функциями надо делать. Ничего не понял.

FIXUPD:

На вход fft как уже выше написано подаётся массив sample[N], где N кратно степени двойки,N=65536, частота дискретизации Fs=44100 то на выходе мы получаем значениея массивов `i[].length=N` и `i[].lingth=N`. Или если говорить по другому, массив комплексных величин C[N].

Как интерпретировать его?

```
C[0] - содержит инфу об частоте 0 герц.
C[1] - содержит инфу об частоте 0.672912598 герц.
C[n] - содержит инфу об частоте n*Fs/N герц.
```

Ссылки:

https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/247385/

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/32class/Complex.java

http://websound.ru/articles/theory/fft.htm

Зеркальный эффект:
http://psi-logic.narod.ru/fft/fft8.htm

Зеркальный эффект вроде является следствием того, что на вход в fft подаются только вещественные значения, без мнимой части? (поправьте мпня если ошибаюсь).

Эффект размазывания:
http://psi-logic.narod.ru/fft/fft9.htm

Статья про практику:
https://habr.com/ru/post/269991/

Предположение:
Зеркальный эффект может возникать из-за того, что на вход подается только реальный сигнал, а не разложеный на I/Q сигнал.

Comment: Как весь этот текст относится к вопросу: `как выделить частоту ноты ? `?

Comment: Добавил код на java, который позволяет уточнить частоты звука. Из частот звука на в выходных данных метода, можно выбрать нужную любым из алгоритмов.