# Java работа со звуком

Tags: java

Хочу поработать со звуком, а именно разбить аудио на звуки, их точки начала, но знаю как преобразовать аудио в то, с чем можно работать. По идее это должно выглядеть как массив, хранящий в себе уровень громкости каждой миллисекунды. Кто может подсказать как сделать что-то подобное?

Comment: А массив байт просто разве не подойдет? Использовать готовый AudioInputStream не то, что надо?

Answer (score 0):

Копайте в сторону алгоритма Фурье.
[Быстрое преобразование Фурье. Как выделить частоту ноты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668267/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B)