# Что можно улучшить в коде?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, чистый-код, naudio, fft

С помощью FFT определены амплитуда, частота и начальная фаза 512 гармоник.
Код преобразования аудио файла с помощью FFT, Program.cs:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace fft
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ms = File.OpenRead(@"d:\source.wav"))
            {
                using (WaveFileReader rdr = new WaveFileReader(ms))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; //4096 buffer size

                    int bytesRead;
                    int total = 0;
                    int count = 0;

                    SampleAggregator sampleAggregator = new SampleAggregator();

                    sampleAggregator.PerformFFT = true;
                    sampleAggregator.FftCalculated += new EventHandler<FftEventArgs>(FftCalculated);

                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = rdr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        count++;

                        for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < bytesRead - 4; startIndex += 4)
                            sampleAggregator.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, startIndex));


                        total += bytesRead;
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);

                    sampleAggregator.PerformFFT = false;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void FftCalculated(object sender, FftEventArgs e)
        {
            int n = e.Result.Length/2;

            float[] X_array = new float[n]; // X real
            float[] Y_array = new float[n]; // Y imaginary
            float[] A_array = new float[n]; // magnitude
            float[] phi_proc = new float[n]; // new phi
            float[] frec = new float[n];

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                float X = e.Result[i].X;
                float Y = e.Result[i].Y;

                X_array[i] = X;
                Y_array[i] = Y;

                // Magnitude = sqrt(X^2 + Y^2)
                float A = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2));
                A_array[i] = A;

                // Phase = ArcTan(Y/X)
                float phi_ = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Atan2(Y, X));
                phi_proc[i] = phi_;

                float F = i * 44100f / (2 * n);
                frec[i] = F;
            }

            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"d:\out.txt");

            sr.Write("{0, 15}{1, 15}{2, 15}", "Амплитуда", "Фаза", "Частота\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                sr.Write("{0, 15}\t{1, 15}\t{2, 15}\n", A_array[i], phi_proc[i], frec[i]);
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

SampleAggregator.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NAudio.Dsp;

namespace fft
{
    public class SampleAggregator
    {
        // volume
        public event EventHandler<MaxSampleEventArgs> MaximumCalculated;
        private float maxValue;
        private float minValue;
        public int NotificationCount { get; set; }
        int count;

        // FFT
        public event EventHandler<FftEventArgs> FftCalculated;
        public bool PerformFFT { get; set; }
        private Complex[] fftBuffer;
        private FftEventArgs fftArgs;
        private int fftPos;
        private int fftLength;
        private int m;

        public SampleAggregator(int fftLength = 1024)
        {
            if (!IsPowerOfTwo(fftLength))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("FFT Length must be a power of two");
            }
            this.m = (int)Math.Log(fftLength, 2.0);
            this.fftLength = fftLength;
            this.fftBuffer = new Complex[fftLength];
            this.fftArgs = new FftEventArgs(fftBuffer);
        }

        bool IsPowerOfTwo(int x)
        {
            return (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
        }


        public void Reset()
        {
            count = 0;
            maxValue = minValue = 0;
        }

        public void Add(float value)
        {
            if (PerformFFT && FftCalculated != null)
            {
                fftBuffer[fftPos].X = (float)(value * FastFourierTransform.HammingWindow(fftPos, fftBuffer.Length));
                fftBuffer[fftPos].Y = 0;
                fftPos++;
                if (fftPos >= fftBuffer.Length)
                {
                    fftPos = 0;
                    // 1024 = 2^10
                    FastFourierTransform.FFT(true, m, fftBuffer);
                    FftCalculated(this, fftArgs);
                }
            }

            maxValue = Math.Max(maxValue, value);
            minValue = Math.Min(minValue, value);
            count++;
            if (count >= NotificationCount && NotificationCount > 0)
            {
                if (MaximumCalculated != null)
                {
                    MaximumCalculated(this, new MaxSampleEventArgs(minValue, maxValue));
                }
                Reset();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MaxSampleEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public MaxSampleEventArgs(float minValue, float maxValue)
        {
            this.MaxSample = maxValue;
            this.MinSample = minValue;
        }
        public float MaxSample { get; private set; }
        public float MinSample { get; private set; }
    }

    public class FftEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public FftEventArgs(Complex[] result)
        {
            this.Result = result;
        }
        public Complex[] Result { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Выводит следующий результат:

```
      Амплитуда           Фаза       Частота
    1,37635E+08        3,141593               0
   9,872906E+07      -0,3174495        43,06641
   2,693165E+07        3,054966        86,13281
   4,057771E+07       -2,695019        129,1992
   3,775276E+07       0,1797561        172,2656
        8874377        2,548879         215,332
   3,056839E+07       -2,072765        258,3984
   3,477777E+07       0,4656045        301,4648
   1,996756E+07       -2,944435        344,5313
        9527217      -0,2522248        387,5977
    3,09956E+07        2,621248        430,6641
   2,766847E+07      -0,1084108        473,7305
   3,245723E+07       -1,624003        516,7969
        8221946        1,382699        559,8633
    3,13396E+07        3,106157        602,9297
   4,747455E+07      -0,1934181        645,9961
   3,064184E+07       -2,467533        689,0625
   1,632683E+07        1,046181        732,1289
        9580996        1,830062        775,1953
   1,733721E+07       -1,386621        818,2617
        2759044        -2,58237        861,3281
        2500503        1,662177        904,3945
        6722505       -1,059276        947,4609
        3197823       -2,659224        990,5273
        4304571       0,6496741        1033,594
        1627016       -2,234364         1076,66
        4146548      -0,8395553        1119,727
        3684058       -3,047166        1162,793
        3232784       0,6181203        1205,859
        4427241         -1,8927        1248,926
        4181582       0,6159479        1291,992
        5726374        -2,39327        1335,059
        1504541        2,070046        1378,125
        2946159       -1,343505        1421,191
        5200244       0,6900653        1464,258
        4010569       -2,121195        1507,324
        1955903       -1,596277        1550,391
        3920184        2,484337        1593,457
        6433642      -0,5926874        1636,523
        2583524        2,366535         1679,59
        1773965       -2,307449        1722,656
        5931704      -0,7929059        1765,723
        8772014        2,176744        1808,789
        6246009       -1,262712        1851,855
        4309498       0,7958669        1894,922
        6315455       -3,030753        1937,988
        7998884      -0,8917868        1981,055
        2486457        1,388703        2024,121
        4185494       -2,464547        2067,188
        1748211        1,871544        2110,254
        1856945       0,2547571         2153,32
        1031907       -1,658766        2196,387
        1266610        -2,95061        2239,453
        2289228     -0,05332185         2282,52
        3114942       -2,808688        2325,586
        2220020     -0,03317619        2368,652
        2220844       -2,469988        2411,719
        1686113      -0,7643628        2454,785
        1047378       -2,660212        2497,852
       615958,3        1,436106        2540,918
        1403766       -1,104017        2583,984
       976041,3        2,601465        2627,051
        2734417      -0,4571997        2670,117
        2911894        3,008721        2713,184
        2621899       -1,100849         2756,25
       982119,1       0,8500024        2799,316
        1847694        2,514631        2842,383
        4606243      -0,7821463        2885,449
        3787969        2,917466        2928,516
        8877559       0,2767128        2971,582
   3,619529E+07       -2,545841        3014,648
   3,148596E+07        0,598125        3057,715
        3746493       -2,472877        3100,781
       830009,3       0,5579143        3143,848
       454884,2        2,318099        3186,914
        1921721       -2,818796         3229,98
        2720334     -0,06990055        3273,047
       773526,5        2,716008        3316,113
       991095,9      -0,3717431         3359,18
       370259,1        2,489391        3402,246
       816891,8      -0,3727157        3445,313
       603778,2        1,898032        3488,379
        1243691       -2,082001        3531,445
        1074989      -0,2578799        3574,512
       66772,98     -0,05730519        3617,578
        1292134       -2,337628        3660,645
        1310137      -0,2033752        3703,711
       618416,1         1,38453        3746,777
       638616,1       -2,753081        3789,844
        1184789      -0,7677395         3832,91
         615659        2,689984        3875,977
        1107154        2,441525        3919,043
        1576492      -0,5585968        3962,109
       652733,1      -0,7071712        4005,176
       948865,8        1,762177        4048,242
        1023113      -0,7465729        4091,309
        1034635       -2,611075        4134,375
        1107797          1,2744        4177,441
        1519462          -1,141        4220,508
       569109,1        2,644734        4263,574
       588931,6      -0,8147474        4306,641
       313872,9       -1,652717        4349,707
        1315602        1,453712        4392,773
        1382194       -1,646547         4435,84
       397498,1        -2,74053        4478,906
        2568746      -0,1058861        4521,973
        3092902       -3,039691        4565,039
        1024402     -0,05963277        4608,105
       707777,4      -0,4127465        4651,172
       195717,4         2,92164        4694,238
       648599,6       -3,063361        4737,305
       671911,4        0,286155        4780,371
       953865,7      -0,8912678        4823,438
         650526       0,8622005        4866,504
        1186269       -2,696839         4909,57
        1078016       0,4043865        4952,637
        1012172       -2,171409        4995,703
       712915,9       0,4397762         5038,77
        1088657       -1,958312        5081,836
       963623,9        1,678041        5124,902
       675288,7       -1,699725        5167,969
         821716      -0,6037893        5211,035
       193930,5       0,9480741        5254,102
       770689,4       -1,730797        5297,168
       668285,1        1,937282        5340,234
       873034,6       -1,132364        5383,301
       346136,1        1,362874        5426,367
         192686       -1,601493        5469,434
       444887,6       -0,337891          5512,5
        36712,4      -0,6167735        5555,566
       171707,9        -1,72992        5598,633
       491799,8      -0,1735717        5641,699
       162790,2         1,71206        5684,766
       774867,9        -1,88205        5727,832
       321691,2       -3,092386        5770,898
...................................................................
       407089,8       0,2651654         8742,48
       355678,1       -2,107224        8785,547
       310083,2        1,086776        8828,613
       164458,8       -1,291515         8871,68
       129096,7      -0,7981789        8914,746
       577172,1       -1,489183        8957,813
       535018,8        1,185401        9000,879
       634055,3       -1,744481        9043,945
       507648,6        1,569295        9087,012
       278733,8       -1,209023        9130,078
       362415,5       0,3832399        9173,145
       532419,3       -2,014296        9216,211
       401044,8       0,4671175        9259,277
       385854,8       -1,755475        9302,344
       122248,9       -1,265652         9345,41
        48546,2       0,6723771        9388,477
       185850,8      -0,2805638        9431,543
       318726,8       -2,021466        9474,609
         120382       0,7419412        9517,676
       279961,8      -0,8201453        9560,742
       291825,1      -0,6727744        9603,809
       560844,9         2,43568        9646,875
       546299,2      -0,9895962        9689,941
       131387,7       0,9339966        9733,008
         391302      -0,7179333        9776,074
       21409,18       -2,997437        9819,141
        90142,8      -0,8544825        9862,207
         391029       -1,984326        9905,273
       293622,8       0,3757861         9948,34
       369789,4       -0,748113        9991,406
       463953,5        2,328602        10034,47
       310653,1      -0,7894809        10077,54
       190959,5      -0,2650703        10120,61
       47492,66       -1,903389        10163,67
       235372,1       -1,175213        10206,74
       234728,5       0,4564956         10249,8
       455498,2       -2,258151        10292,87
       449732,8        0,799491        10335,94
       203316,5       -1,324437           10379
       85121,31      -0,4261258        10422,07
       273546,6       -1,375018        10465,14
         175015        3,079525         10508,2
       121348,3       0,2721767        10551,27
       431120,8      -0,3579329        10594,34
       347832,1          2,2752         10637,4
       655489,1       -1,457085        10680,47
       208940,7        1,545835        10723,54
       110208,8       -1,210837         10766,6
       136959,6        2,334763        10809,67
       646642,6      -0,4615363        10852,73
       275528,1       -2,956884         10895,8
       264023,6       0,4015069        10938,87
       257054,7       -1,389444        10981,93
       96765,98        2,173659           11025
       89608,51      -0,9954699        11068,07
       366929,9       -1,535273        11111,13
       467821,4       0,9709223         11154,2
         192946        2,894901        11197,27
       486996,1       -1,225242        11240,33
       249776,6      0,04803916         11283,4
       199946,5       -2,763811        11326,46
       290771,2      -0,3811239        11369,53
       254724,4        3,006238         11412,6
         388126      -0,3031629        11455,66
         201632       -3,046822        11498,73
       467290,1       -0,585902         11541,8
       424830,9        2,134953        11584,86
       463910,3       -1,185225        11627,93
       186633,4        2,299737           11671
       265882,6       -1,058136        11714,06
       540958,3       0,8847211        11757,13
       348871,1       -1,873847         11800,2
       42848,82       -2,989112        11843,26
       228773,1      -0,8439134        11886,33
       116892,1      0,05488167        11929,39
         127908        2,345144        11972,46
       499440,8       -1,339604        12015,53
       436530,1        1,239592        12058,59
       281511,6       -1,388246        12101,66
       128884,6        1,696337        12144,73
       285539,3      -0,7990029        12187,79
       215221,6         2,41503        12230,86
       212511,2      -0,8346258        12273,93
       286025,1      -0,2285509        12316,99
       173265,6        2,810702        12360,06
       179124,4       0,1145218        12403,13
       181786,8       -1,939869        12446,19
       399855,4    -0,003901795        12489,26
       275812,7       -2,950712        12532,32
       99744,02        0,967459        12575,39
       77759,06       0,2980953        12618,46
       439379,4      -0,9125478        12661,52
       327063,8        2,155473        12704,59
       303660,3       -0,432981        12747,66
       439110,2       -2,682404        12790,72
       375834,6       0,5313507        12833,79
       692050,9       -1,144768        12876,86
       899157,5        2,037639        12919,92
       553065,6       -1,218552        12962,99
       387296,2      -0,1003001        13006,05
       273863,8       -1,938238        13049,12
       301825,4        1,427282        13092,19
       265484,4       -1,779614        13135,25
       137390,9       0,2286138        13178,32
       338550,3      -0,3008576        13221,39
       320558,2        2,995403        13264,45
       492184,9       -0,912329        13307,52
       314383,6        1,254047        13350,59
       233947,1       -1,300414        13393,65
       52128,86      -0,2290096        13436,72
         189073     -0,05959874        13479,79
       43716,71        3,106588        13522,85
       218084,8      -0,8031774        13565,92
         254938        2,787258        13608,98
       422808,8      -0,6583306        13652,05
       133323,6        2,193803        13695,12
       262140,5      -0,1007498        13738,18
       201085,6        2,236696        13781,25
         526387       -1,117748        13824,32
       127898,9        3,004457        13867,38
          75073        1,217288        13910,45
       234179,2      -0,5897456        13953,52
       205216,3       0,9480705        13996,58
       154677,2       -1,163525        14039,65
       101789,9        -2,19061        14082,71
       70660,41      -0,9976465        14125,78
       160737,7      -0,7375044        14168,85
       33656,25       0,6239181        14211,91
       72595,66       0,2986096        14254,98
       240884,5       -2,028966        14298,05
       332211,1       0,4460075        14341,11
         170656       -1,950373        14384,18
        58296,8       0,1520191        14427,25
       215829,9      -0,2801605        14470,31
       142457,4       -2,538587        14513,38
       171582,1        0,356312        14556,45
       237834,8       -1,400423        14599,51
       107239,4         2,43935        14642,58
       239289,1       0,3403818        14685,64
       129985,9       -1,067518        14728,71
       222832,1      -0,4511884        14771,78
       107144,2       -2,367797        14814,84
       74223,79        1,468154        14857,91
       202884,6      -0,7028238        14900,98
       94931,53      -0,2352982        14944,04
       24525,81       -1,664078        14987,11
       247106,7        1,680805        15030,18
       489472,3      -0,9126853        15073,24
       242411,5        2,397371        15116,31
       214493,6      -0,8062004        15159,38
       14358,52       -2,970088        15202,44
       228372,2      0,07976476        15245,51
       237966,5       -2,525232        15288,57
         238895       0,5377389        15331,64
       227006,8       -1,018389        15374,71
       62815,55       -1,915184        15417,77
       59146,21       0,3909755        15460,84
       217516,4       0,1088751        15503,91
        48396,8        3,085744        15546,97
       19491,73       -1,106534        15590,04
       154407,6       -1,227129        15633,11
       197445,2      -0,6012994        15676,17
         208898        1,682533        15719,24
       407386,4       -1,002899         15762,3
          63866       -3,118124        15805,37
         206151        1,561113        15848,44
       279238,6        -1,03722         15891,5
       20755,63        1,659211        15934,57
       207772,9      0,06274817        15977,64
       67124,13        2,505021         16020,7
       180185,4       -1,251169        16063,77
       254831,6       0,3275275        16106,84
       193584,7       -2,579321         16149,9
        31936,7        2,996479        16192,97
       323402,2      -0,5959395        16236,04
       271104,1        1,112661         16279,1
         292882       -1,481264        16322,17
       168304,4         1,02441        16365,23
       55663,51       -1,793853         16408,3
       85871,41      -0,4980028        16451,37
       172433,2        1,411605        16494,43
       350143,5       -1,182185         16537,5
       48604,67      -0,1564384        16580,57
       34959,98       0,2479544        16623,63
       156579,3      -0,5921221         16666,7
       116151,3       -2,662918        16709,77
       258779,3       0,4845772        16752,83
       45198,96       -1,359202         16795,9
       70406,92      -0,6723601        16838,96
       66774,18      -0,8966588        16882,03
       128428,4       -0,617744         16925,1
       140979,3        1,587383        16968,16
         280834       -1,128473        17011,23
         102337       -2,502975         17054,3
       283287,5       0,3265435        17097,36
       151975,3       -2,643661        17140,43
       201590,2      -0,3267642         17183,5
       118359,8       0,9091799        17226,56
       179498,1       -1,415487        17269,63
       202394,2        1,396686         17312,7
       231037,3      -0,7043558        17355,76
       41419,77       -2,926986        17398,83
         185915       -1,523513        17441,89
       126872,6        1,906348        17484,96
       219416,2      -0,7838139        17528,03
       183797,3      -0,3128181        17571,09
       42174,49        2,389735        17614,16
       169301,4      -0,2982703        17657,23
       37117,43        2,984656        17700,29
       97238,13        1,459621        17743,36
       82646,74      -0,4535268        17786,43
       71865,59    -0,008223356        17829,49
       111838,8        2,243133        17872,56
       90411,02        -1,12074        17915,63
       278247,2       -1,015702        17958,69
       154384,5       -2,692111        18001,76
       135247,4     -0,03473107        18044,82
       343375,9      -0,7261079        18087,89
       269568,2       0,1009461        18130,96
        1064260      -0,4961446        18174,02
        4318394        2,557522        18217,09
        3817022      -0,4996571        18260,16
       253924,6         1,32888        18303,22
       155257,8        2,030647        18346,29
       200382,8        1,432151        18389,36
         134515       0,9798414        18432,42
       87995,19      -0,4506082        18475,49
       68341,77        1,571618        18518,55
       34704,02        1,545008        18561,62
       217592,7       -1,146028        18604,69
       45598,66        1,715822        18647,75
       137021,3      -0,2546101        18690,82
       36449,06       0,0425174        18733,89
       184063,4      -0,4431018        18776,95
       154889,7       0,7162107        18820,02
         171592      0,02029408        18863,09
       191761,6       -2,868127        18906,15
       137085,2      -0,1173551        18949,22
         218939       0,8032717        18992,29
       202394,6       -2,117162        19035,35
       232593,6       0,2800354        19078,42
       100331,3       -2,235241        19121,48
       277506,9         0,85051        19164,55
       224497,2       -1,515977        19207,62
       133286,8       0,4950542        19250,68
       62575,92       -1,893883        19293,75
       307186,1        0,576763        19336,82
       196983,4       -1,480692        19379,88
       171627,4        1,195461        19422,95
       97067,67       -2,564923        19466,02
       203645,6      -0,1813843        19509,08
       32216,71      -0,3762972        19552,15
         174123       -1,284576        19595,21
       211578,5       0,7129873        19638,28
       47298,41       -1,632651        19681,35
       204052,8      -0,1317645        19724,41
       99191,77       -1,610497        19767,48
       53945,24        1,640093        19810,55
       134271,2        1,032663        19853,61
       163449,4      -0,2928131        19896,68
        79200,4      -0,1318209        19939,75
       86771,17       -3,107662        19982,81
       181193,2      -0,4431666        20025,88
       100615,4      -0,2202356        20068,95
       69420,39        3,128529        20112,01
       231349,8      0,04048931        20155,08
        92054,8        1,654247        20198,14
       47710,43      -0,8525124        20241,21
       156213,2      -0,6774409        20284,28
       161189,2       0,9777452        20327,34
       115269,6       -1,923447        20370,41
       148665,8       0,5388893        20413,48
       117696,5       -1,574587        20456,54
       92606,59        0,300347        20499,61
       145723,1       0,3891755        20542,68
       112504,9      -0,8060678        20585,74
       73474,25       -2,336761        20628,81
       256318,7         0,23377        20671,88
       24250,88       -2,250594        20714,94
       160476,2      -0,4384546        20758,01
        15034,2        1,247216        20801,07
       139379,5       0,8427607        20844,14
       114546,1       -1,546166        20887,21
       81208,93        0,320226        20930,27
       43770,13         -1,4137        20973,34
         161747         0,20294        21016,41
       124452,9       -2,202655        21059,47
       208195,3       0,4855228        21102,54
       92038,16       -1,055747        21145,61
       129751,5        0,381626        21188,67
       38776,03      0,06692123        21231,74
         103451       0,4821521         21274,8
       77022,04      -0,9981962        21317,87
         125995      -0,1490869        21360,94
       57013,56        1,601962           21404
       50614,99      -0,6230396        21447,07
       94630,76      -0,1863516        21490,14
       91186,84       0,1544781         21533,2
       99161,91      -0,3041609        21576,27
       46391,44       0,3795729        21619,34
        91104,3     -0,05825521         21662,4
        62201,8       0,5848758        21705,47
       77783,59      -0,2326978        21748,54
       54642,25       0,7926224         21791,6
       93077,99      -0,4236717        21834,67
       47430,64      0,09272207        21877,73
       104056,9      -0,2599141         21920,8
        30258,8        0,235479        21963,87
        92160,1      -0,2369028        22006,93
```

Что можно улучшить в коде?

Comment: Если бы мне подобный код попал на ревью - у меня практически не было бы к нему замечаний. У вас в одном месте после метода стоит две пустых строки, хотя обычно вы ставите одну. В остальном же хороший, чистый код. С FFT знаком только в теории, поэтому возможно что-то и можно подкрутить -- но уже на уровне алгоритмов, а не оформления кода.

Comment: Если присваивание только в конструкторе - сеттер не нужен `public float MaxSample { get; }`

Comment: `using StreamWriter sr ...` и убрать `sr.Close()`

Comment: Вместо `(float)Math.Sqrt` можно `MathF.Sqrt`, то же самое позволит избавиться от `Convert.ToSingle`

Comment: Для вычисления амплитуды лучше использовать Hypot. В выводимой таблице частота в последнем столбце - почему так? Столбец амплитуды смотрится не очень из-за использования двух форматов.

Comment: @MBo, [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668267/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что должна проиллюстрировать та ветка. Если про частоту, то мысли такие - у вас зависимость амплитуды и фазы от частоты, а в таких случаях принято в первом столбце приводить x, а в следующих - F(x).

Comment: @MBo, там на счёт частоты: "То есть, на выходе получив 1024 значений комплексных получаем 1024 значений амплитуда-фаза. Из этих значений, располагая массив по порядку и амплитуде можно получить нечто вроде визуализации амплитуды звука по частоте.

Если дискретизация 44100Гц, а входной массив имеет длину 65536 то шаг между элементами массива на выходе получается 0.672912598 Гц."

Comment: @MBo, И: "На вход fft как уже выше написано подаётся массив sample[N], где N кратно степени двойки,N=65536, частота дискретизации Fs=44100 то на выходе мы получаем значениея массивов i[].length=N и i[].lingth=N. Или если говорить по другому, массив комплексных величин C[N].

Как интерпретировать его?

C[0] - содержит инфу об частоте 0 герц.
C[1] - содержит инфу об частоте 0.672912598 герц.
C[n] - содержит инфу об частоте n*Fs/N герц.
"

Comment: Там человек объясняет, как получить частоту по номеру отсчёта, зная частоту дискретизации и размерность преобразования. Однако ориентация столбиков - вывод первичной величины после вторичных - скажем так, нетрадиционная.