# Как найти СКО (среднеквадратическое отклонение) белого шума в аудио файле wave на C#?

Tags: c#, naudio, fft, фурье

Как найти СКО (среднеквадратическое отклонение) белого шума в аудио файле wave на C#?

Comment: А при чем тут fft и Фурье?

Comment: А так берете просто стандартную функцию для высчитывания СКО и вперед: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Из общих соображений - нужно перевести сигнал в частоты (преобразование Фурье), выпилить частоты сигнала (те, у которых частотная полоса узкая, а амплитуда высокая), у того, что останется, посчитать среднюю амплитуду и средний квадрат амплитуды.

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Вот мой код [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294246/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2282294_1294246], который создает три массива с данными - частота, амплитуда и фаза. С помощью этих данных как то можно получить СКО белого шума, по крайней мере так говорят

Answer (score 0):

Это не ответ, а предложение уточнить задачу. Комментарии слишком малы, чтобы вместить ))

Во-первых, понятие шум/сигнал здорово зависит от природы сигнала. Одно дело, музыка. Другое - звуки природы. Третье - записи сигналов, принятых радиотелескопом. В каждом из этих сценариев требуется своё понятие шума.

Во-вторых, само понятие шума. Вот представьте, вы дома или в офисе записываете речь на диктофон, а за окном гудит федеральное шоссе. Шорох шин, гудки, взрыки моторов - для вашей записи они шум, так как ваша цель записать голос. Но для диктофона это вполне себе нормальный сигнал, который попал в микрофон.

В-третьих, требование белости шума. Вообще говоря, это очень сильное требование. В реальной жизни шум всегда не белый и концентрируется вокруг каких-то особых частот. В старых магнитофонах это были резонансные частоты лентопротяжного механизма, мотора, вибраций корпуса. Потом появились резонансные частоты усилителей. В нынешние времена это особенности цифровых фильтров. Например, недавно разговаривал с женой через гарнитуру, так она вся изругалась на посторонние шумы, которые угодили в частоты человеческой речи и оказались усилены системой шумоподавления.

В-четвёртых, сам сигнал не постоянен во времени. Например, в музыке спектр сигнала меняется от такта к такту. Поэтому, по-хорошему, нужно вычленять шумы в каждом такте. Соответственно, обрабатывать не всю запись чохом, а дробить её на такты, что требует отдельного интеллекта от программы.

Итого. Создание цифровых фильтров - это большое техномагическое шаманство. Не зная, к чему именно вы собираетесь применять свой измеритель шума, нельзя толком предложить решение. Хоть намекните, какого рода сигнал вы собираетесь обрабатывать и дайте пример записи.

Comment: Сигнал такого вида: https://www.dropbox.com/s/31bmlhv3bobi669/source.wav?dl=0, а как вычислить СКО, дана информация в качестве "эталона" вот здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/253447/